# Activity being completely skipped

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

I know this might seem like a very dumb or easy question to fix but in all honesty, I have tried so much to fix this. My application is supposed to display a welcome activity upon completing the profile activity like adding your first name and last name etc...

Below is the code used to set up the users profile as they fill in the required fields such as first name, last name, age, and gender

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Grab firebaseAuth objects
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    //Set app to full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    //Get all views
    firstName = findViewById(R.id.profile_firstName);
    lastName = findViewById(R.id.profile_lastName);
    male = findViewById(R.id.profile_male);
    female = findViewById(R.id.profile_female);
    age = findViewById(R.id.profile_age);
    button = findViewById(R.id.profile_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    //If no user is logged in send them back to Login page
    if (firebaseUser == null)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}

private void createUser()
{
    String first_name = firstName.getText().toString().trim();
    String last_name = lastName.getText().toString().trim();

    String gender = "";

    if (male.isChecked())
    {
        gender = "male";
    }

    if (female.isChecked())
    {
        gender = "female";
    }

    if (male.isChecked() && female.isChecked())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please only select one gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (male.isChecked() == false && female.isChecked() == false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    int years;

    if (age.getText().toString().length() == 0)
    {
        years = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        years = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
    }



    boolean profileComplete;

    //Check if profileComplete should be true or false
    if (first_name.length() == 0 || last_name.length() == 0 || gender.length() == 0 || years == 0 || gender.length() == 0)
    {
        profileComplete = false;
    }

    else
    {
        profileComplete = true;
    }

    User user = new User(first_name, last_name, gender, years, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), profileComplete);

    //Create a new node for each individual user
    firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user);

    //Bring them into the welcome screen
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view == button)
    {
        createUser();
    }
}
```

After the user object is fully completed and sent to the database we can clearly see the activity starts a new activity called WelcomeActivity. This has a Log.i at the very start that never fires and instead the ViewProfileActivity runs.

Here is the WelcomeActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i("WelcomeActivity", "We made it to the WelcomeActivity!");

    //Set app to full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    //Grab firebaseAuth objects
    String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users/" + currentUserId);

    welcomeUser = findViewById(R.id.id_welcome_user);

    final User user = new User();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            user.setFirstName(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getFirstName());
            welcomeUser.setText(user.getFirstName().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });


}
```

And here is the ViewProfileActivity (This should run AFTER welcome activity. Now there is no intent from welcomeActivity to run the ViewProfileActivity because I cant even get it to go there in the first place as of now.):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set app to full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);

    //Grab firebaseAuth objects
    String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users/" + currentUserId);

     final TextView view_profile_firstName = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_firstname);
     final TextView view_profile_lastName = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_lastname);
     final TextView view_profile_email = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_email);
     final TextView view_profile_age = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_age);
     final TextView view_profile_gender = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_gender);
     final TextView view_profile_profileComplete = findViewById(R.id.view_profile_profilecomplete);

     final User user = new User();

     databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
         {
             user.setFirstName(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getFirstName());
             view_profile_firstName.setText(user.getFirstName().toString());

             user.setLastName(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getLastName());
             view_profile_lastName.setText(user.getLastName().toString());

             user.setEmail(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getEmail());
             view_profile_email.setText(user.getEmail().toString());

             user.setAge(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getAge());
             view_profile_age.setText(Integer.toString(user.getAge()));

             user.setGender(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getGender());
             view_profile_gender.setText(user.getGender());

             user.setProfileComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getProfileComplete());
             view_profile_profileComplete.setText(String.valueOf(user.getProfileComplete()));

         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
         {

         }
     });


}
```

At first the

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
```

was wrong and held the layout.activity_view_profile. I thought to fix this would have easily fixed my issues but nothing seemed to change. I have rebuilt and cleaned my project fully uninstalled the apk and reinstalled it on both the emulator and the physical device, nothing will seem to work. I imagine it is a coding error but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

My hypothesis was other activities were running and their onDataChange method was checking constantly and executing the intent to the ViewProfileActivity but I put finish() at the end of each startActivity().

All help is much appreciated as this is limiting my progression with this app. As of now, I will continue research until I find a solution.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Registration" />
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

UPDATE:
I was able to get the WelcomeActivity to finally show AFTER I commented out the code within this if statement.

```
@Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        user.setProfileComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getProfileComplete());

                        //The profileComplete method returns TRUE, so we can skip the profile creation.
                        if(user.getProfileComplete())
                        {
                            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewProfileActivity.class);
                            //startActivity(intent);
                            //finish();
                        }

                        //the profileComplete method returns FALSE, we must send the user to the profile creation.
                        else
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
```

This code is found within the MainActivity and is used to determin if the users profile is complete or not. If its not complete it sends them to create a profile otherwise it immedently sends them to view there profile.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `createUser` gets run and makes it to the end of the function?

Comment: I followed it all the way down with a debugger and yes it executes all the way down.

Comment: I just ran a debugger and it shows that it runs all the way and the startActivity(intent) in the ProfileActivity.java shows:
"Intent { cmp=com.example.aleksei.meep/.WelcomeActivity }" implying that it is pointing to the correct activity.

Comment: That's puzzling then. Can you post the manifest xml?

Comment: Sure thing I will do that right now

Comment: Are you still having problems with this or is it solved (seeing your last edit)??? If it is solved you should revert your last edit and post it as an answer so other people can see your question has been answered. (Nothing wrong with answering your own question :) )

Comment: Well I believe I fixed it. I just used a simple boolean variable that prevents the MainActivities method from being called when the firebase data add changes, that's what was causing the issue. I just feel like that was not the proper fix but yes it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is you haven't created the activity that you want to load up first.

**Solution 1 :**
Try to click the app

[image]

and select `Edit Configuration` and set the activity to run on your designated Activity
[image]

**Solution 2 :**

In your `.xml` file, make your desired activity to launch first like this

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />      <--- add this 2 lines
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <---
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and remove the old one.

Comment: But doesn't that just change the first activity that starts?

Comment: may I know the flow? the questions a bit confusing

Comment: So the app starts on login screen, but a new user taps to go to registration and after making an account goes back to login to well.. login. Upon logging in it checks if you have already been through the profile creation screen or not. If you havent it brings you to ProfileActivity, then after making a profile it should bring you to WelcomeActivity THEN ViewProfileActivity. Right now its skipping entirly over WelcomeActivity. If the user already has an account made it skips ProfileActivity therefore also skipping WelcomeActivity bringing them striaght into the core of the app, ViewProfileAct..

Answer (score 0):

Simply put I created a variable called loggedIn that is false at the start and turns into true immediately after the user logs in and either skips the profile creation or not. This prevents the method onDataChange from ever being called by the MainActivity again in the future. I am just unaware of any other solutions, If anyone knows of another way please don't hesitate to respond. Otherwise, thank you all for the support!

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if (loggedIn == false)
                        {
                            user.setProfileComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getProfileComplete());

                            //The profileComplete method returns TRUE, so we can skip the profile creation.
                            if(user.getProfileComplete())
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewProfileActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                loggedIn = true;
                            }

                            //the profileComplete method returns FALSE, we must send the user to the profile creation.
                            else
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                loggedIn = true;

                            }
                        }

                    }
```